# Is it possible to assign a value from local function to a global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Hey guys I have declared a global variable in my javascript file.Then iam assigning a value to the global variable in a local function.Then when iam trying to access the value of that global variable in other function,damn alert box is showing 'undefined'.Is there any way to access the value of a local variable in other function.I don't want to call the function from another function and send parameters with it.I just want to access the local variable of one function into some another function.
Hope someone takes me out of this.

Thank you guys and girls.

the code

```
   var user_glob;
   var pass_glob;
   function osmlogin() {
       var user = document.getElementById('uname').value;
       var passw = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
       user_glob = user;
       pass_glob = passw;
       if (user == '') {
           document.getElementById('wrong_pwd').innerHTML = 'Please give your email_id';
       }
       else if (passw == '') {
           document.getElementById('wrong_pwd').innerHTML = 'Please give your password';
       }
       else {
           var data =
             {
                 username: user,
                 pass: passw

             };


           $.getJSON('some url?jsonp=?', data, function (data) {

               check = JSON.stringify(data['key1']);
               if (check == 1 && user != '' && passw != '') {


                   window.location.href = "#page-dashboard";
               }

               else {

                   // alert(check);

                   document.getElementById('wrong_pwd').innerHTML = 'Wrong Username or Password';
               }

           });
       }
   }
```

now I want to use that global variable in this function

```
 function  announcement_view()
 {

var user =user_glob;
var passw = passw_glob;
 var data = {
    username: user,
    pass:passw

 };



$.getJSON('some url?jsonp=?', data, function (data) {

    var check = JSON.stringify(data['key1']);
    alert(JSON.stringify(data['key1']));
    alert(JSON.stringify(data['key2']));


    if (check == 0 && user == '' && passw == '')
    {

        //alert(user_glob);
       window.location.href = "#page-home";
    }



  });
}
```

Comment: This should work according to your *description* however if you showed some code it might become clear.

Comment: It's exactly what @RobSchmuecker said. I wrote a jsfiddle about it: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbenseler/5fhyamfu/ it's better if you write some code and show us.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is something like this...

```
var a;
function f1(){
    a= 1;
}
function f2(){
    alert(a);
}

f1();
f2();
```

It should work fine.

Make sure you are calling the function that ***assigns*** the value (f1 in this case) before the function that alerts it (f2 in this case).